# Changing to dark mode in android isn't very smooth

Tags: android

I am using the material components DayNight theme for my app. And I want to switch on/off the dark mode at runtime. I am using the following method to change the theme of the app:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode();
```

The problem is that it recreates the activity which is not very smooth. It shows a black screen before changing the app theme.

Is there a way I can make this look smooth?

Answer (score 2):

set theme to Dark mode before super.create() method is called, so before activity is visible to user, it's theme will be first changed.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I am setting the dark mode in the application class. Also calling setDetaultNightMode should recreate the activity, which is not happening for me.

Comment: thanks for answering. Although this is only happening in the emulator. Works smoothly in device.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in your Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    delegate.localNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
}
```

to remove it again:

```
delegate.localNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM
```